# How to debug a "native app" page with already opened activity with appium

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium

So I have already run a test with Appium and got a specific page on the native app(Android).
the app requires a login and the page I would like to debug and test is the 5th, while all the 4 before has some required fields to fill in.
I'm tired of waiting to get this page each time I want to test an Element on the 5th page.
any suggestions how to get this 5th page? even in terms of not closing the app. I have tried "noRest = True" in the capabilities.

Comment: can your app(under test) ever do that? i mean go directly from login to 5th page?

Comment: Also if this 5th page is a different activity all together you can try using `driver.startActivity` method in appium

Comment: @nullpointer no my app can't do that. go directly from login to the 5th page.unfortunately,  I have already tried the driver.startActivity. it didn't work.

Comment: What you tried can be shared to explore more.

Comment: @nullpointer - sorry for the late response.
The problem is that most of the screeen seemingly has the same "appActivity".
it looks like this:
com.foo.android.device.activity.Myactivity

Comment: if its the same activity, what you are looking for is to launch a specific `fragment` inside it which I doubt is still not supported by Appium

Comment: yes, this been an issue for a long time(similar to Autosuggestion elements). anyway I can keep the session open when 1st test is over in order to run the 2nd test from the same place the 1st one ended? is it possible? just been thiniking about this workaround for me

Comment: @nullpointer - sorry forgot to tag you. do you think I can do that somehow?

Comment: you can keep the session continued, just that what you want to test is decisive on your end. Also to directly land to a page you might want to navigate to the fragment you want to interact with.

Comment: @nullpointer how do I find which fragment is it and how can I navigate there directly? I thought it is impossible with Appium.